# Cant' intercept the JFrame termination event by the shutdown() method in a SingleFrameApplication, why?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am pretty new in Java **Swing** development and I have the following problem.

I am working on an application that use Swing **JDesktop** framework.

So I have the following 2 classes:

1) **GUI.java**:

```
package com.test.login2;

import org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication;


public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication {

    // Estensione di JFrame:
    private MainFrame mainFrame = null;

    @Override
    protected void startup() {
        System.out.println("GUI ---> startUp()");
        mainFrame = new MainFrame();
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    }

    // Save session state for the component hierarchy rooted by the mainFrame:
    @Override
    protected void shutdown() {
        System.out.println("ShutDown event intercepted by the GUI ---> sutdown() method");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("GUI ---> main()");

        /* Creates an instance of the specified Application subclass (SingleFrameApplication), 
         * sets the ApplicationContext application property, and then calls the new Application's startup method. 
         */
        launch(GUI.class, args);

    }

}
```

As you can see in this class there is the **main()** method that simply perform this operation:

```
launch(GUI.class, args);
```

Reading on the official docimentation: [launch() doc](http://bellquel.bo.cnr.it/appframework/org/jdesktop/application/Application.html#launch%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

> Creates an instance of the specified Application subclass, sets the
>   ApplicationContext application property, and then calls the new
>   Application's startup method. The launch method is typically called
>   from the Application's main. The applicationClass constructor and startup methods run on the event dispatching thread.

So the **startup()** method is executed and there is created and show a new **MainFrame** object

2) So this is the **MainFrame** code (it simply extends a classic Swing **JFrame**):

```
package com.test.login2;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.test.login.LoginFrame;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final int FIXED_WIDTH = 1000;
    private static final Dimension INITAL_SIZE = new Dimension(FIXED_WIDTH, 620);

    private final Action actionLogOut = new AbstractAction() {
        {
            putValue(Action.NAME, ("LogOut"));
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("MainWindows ---> actionPerformed()");
            JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource();
            Window window = SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(button);
            //window.setVisible(false); 
            //window.dispose();

        }
    };

    public MainFrame() {
        super();

        setPreferredSize(INITAL_SIZE);
        setResizable(false);

        setTitle("My Application");
        setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));

        add(new JButton(actionLogOut));     // Add the LogOut JButton to the current MainFrame object

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        // Center the window

    }


}
```

At this stage this is not very important the presence of the **JButton** and of the relative listener.

My problem is the following one:

As you can see in the **GUI.java** class is definied a **shutdown()** method (that is definied in the **SingleFrameApplication** abstact class).

[shutdown() method doc](http://bellquel.bo.cnr.it/appframework/org/jdesktop/application/SingleFrameApplication.html#shutdown%28%29)

Reading the documentation:

> Save session state for the component hierarchy rooted by the
>   mainFrame.

So the main() method of **GUI.java** class perform the operation that execute the **startup()** method that create and show the **MainFrame** object (and untill here it is clear)

Then I would that when I click on the X button (the button that close the JFrame), the **shutdown()** method (of the **GUI.java** class) is performed. I can't intercept this event and this is a big problem for me

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Have you considered adding a `WindowListener` on your `JFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

I use a window listener something like this. You can use this right in the constructor for your MainFrame class

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            //do all your saving
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

do note that the System.exit(0); command will close your entire application. So this exact code shouldnt be used in a situation where you want to just close a jframe and not close the entire application.